# How to check current running apache server path on MacOS X?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I forget the current running apache server path.... But I sure that I am running an apache server. How can I search the current running apache server path? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

apache conf should be in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf

Comment: ...or `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (to which `/etc` is a symbolic link). When in doubt, `httpd -V|grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE` will show its location too.

Comment: thx arjan....i'm sure i'll get it running over here eventually just can't afford it atm so i'm stuck with google magic